# Paypal review page customization with rest api in php

Tags: paypal

How can i do this:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/

In rest api, especially when dealing with recurring payments,when my summary is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to display the details of the plan on the order summary page at this time. We have raised the issue internally in Paypal, and got an issue created here https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/149. We will be updating the issue on github, for any changes.

However, you can still provide some description as shown here: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/billing/CreateBillingAgreementWithCreditCard.php#L58